# Custom arrow shapes in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

The `tikz-cd` package comes with plenty of arrow head and tail options, but there are some more adventurous applications that are harder to implement. In my particular case, I would like to replace the arrow with a long triangle, as illustrated in this mock-up:

[image]

There are dedicated chemistry notation packages with this kind of arrow/bond packages available, but I want the output to be consistent with the other diagrams I have in my work, so a `tikz-cd`-based option would be preferred. A solid triangle would also be acceptable if that is easier for whatever reason.

MWE (outputs dashed line where I would like the triangle to be):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
K \ar[dr,dashed, no head] & & \\
& A \ar[dr,two heads] & \\
& & X
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question would be nice, so that helpers would not be forced to do all the job.

Comment: Pretty sure an MWE is more useful for identifying problems/sources of errors in code, but okay, I've added one.

Comment: Thank you. A MWE is also useful to copy/paste and strat adding what you need ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here's a solution that involves `remember picture` and to draw afterwards your `tikz-cd`, but I think it could be enough for your purpose.

[image: new arrow type on tikz-cd]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\triar}[2]{
    \draw[orange] ($(#2)!0.2!(#1)$) -- ($ (#2)!0.8! 10:(#1) $) -- ($ (#2)!0.8! -10:(#1) $)  --cycle;
    }
    
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzcd}[remember picture]
        |[alias=K]|K  & & \\
        & |[alias=A]|A \ar[dr,two heads] & \\
        & & X
    \end{tikzcd}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \triar{K}{A};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you're not familiar with the `calc` library, when you type `($ (#2)!0.8! 10:(#1) $)`, it means the point between arg2 and arg1 (here between A and K), but with an additional turn by 10°. The triangle is made with this. You can change the value of the angle like you want.

Of course, the orange colour is only here to emphasize the new arrow.

#### EDIT

Here's a little variation, letting you pass the angle as a parameter, because on more complex diagrams, it could be interesting to customize that point.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\triar}[3]{
    \draw[orange] ($(#2)!0.1!(#1)$) -- ($ (#2)!0.9! #3:(#1) $) -- ($ (#2)!0.9! -#3:(#1) $)  --cycle;
    }
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[remember picture]
        |[alias=A]|A \arrow{d} \arrow{r}[near start]{\phi}[near end]{\psi}
        & |[alias=B]|B  & |[alias=E]| E\\
        |[alias=C]|C \arrow[red]{r}[blue,below]{\eta}
        & |[alias=D]|D \arrow[purple]{r}[green,below]{\nu} & |[alias=F]| F
    \end{tikzcd}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \triar{E}{C}{2};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I also changed the percentage to .1 and .9 for start and end of the triangle, it seems better to me like this.

[image: custom arrow shape 2]

And of course, I know this commutative diagram is absurd, it's just to show the new arrow properties.

Comment: If I wanted to do this for arrows in different directions or at different lengths, do you expect it would adapt okay?

Comment: Since the triangle is drawn using direct coordinates of the nodes, I think yes. You may try by yourself. I'll try also.

Comment: Post edited accordingly. Hope this fullfills your needs.

Comment: You did a great job.