# How can I use a modified arrow in a tikz-cd diagram?

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd

I need to make a commutative diagram with arrows that are themselves marked as incoming or outgoing. After some fiddling I produced this command, which produces an acceptable shape:

```
\newcommand{\outgoingarrow}{\ooalign{$\longrightarrow$\!\!\!\!\!\scalebox{2.4}{\raisebox{-4.5pt}{$\widehat{}$}}}}
```

[image: Arrow marked as outgoing.]

Now I just need to use it in commutative diagrams. But it doesn't seem I can just use the shape in tikz-cd diagrams. I found this answer:

[Custom arrow shapes in tikzcd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614173/custom-arrow-shapes-in-tikzcd)

But it seems fairly cumbersome for a barely modified arrow shape like this. Isn't there some way I can get tikz-cd to simply recognize my modified arrow shape?

Comment: Can you show how the arrow should look, i.e. an image? While there is a way to use typeset text as a tip a lot can already be done with normal “real” tips.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I added a picture.

Comment: Should the “hat” be right before the usual tip or halfway a long the whole line? How does this mark it as incoming or outgoing? Isn't that the job of the > at the end?

Comment: It's supposed to be in the middle. It's not about denoting the source and target of the arrow but denoting that the arrow itself is an input or output of a higher cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can use the `marking` option to place a symbol on an arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[r,"\uparrow"marking]\arrow[d] & B\arrow[d]\\
C\arrow[r,"\downarrow"marking] & D
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Or you can use `\wedge` and `\vee` instead of `\uparrow` and `\downarrow`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with something.

You can just place the `\widehat` like any other node along the path.

Here I define a `hat` key that does all this for you.

- `sloped`, `allow upside down` and `midway` make sure that the “tip” follows the slope of the line and stays in the middle irregardless of other settings.
- `yscale` and `yshift` just sacles and moves the hat around so that it looks good. This might need to be adjusted for other fonts.

You can use any symbol here of course and also rotate it however you need.

You can also use any TikZ drawing which is what I have done with the `outgoing` pic that is just drawing a orthogonal line to the path.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\tikzcdset{
  tikzcd to small/.tip={tikzcd to[scale=.5, sep=+0pt +1]},
  edge node/.style={/tikz/every to/.append style={edge node={#1}}},
  /tikz/pics/outgoing/.style={
    /tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down, code={
      \draw[pic actions] (0pt,0pt) -- (up:1ex);}},
  outgoing/.style={edge node={pic[-tikzcd to small,#1]{outgoing}}},
  outgoing'/.style={edge node={pic[-tikzcd to small,yscale=-1,#1]{outgoing}}},
  incoming/.style={edge node={pic[tikzcd to small-,#1]{outgoing}}},
  incoming'/.style={edge node={pic[tikzcd to small-,yscale=-1,#1]{outgoing}}},
  hat/.style={edge node={
    node[sloped, allow upside down, inner sep=+0pt, midway,
         yscale=2, yshift=-.6ex]{$\widehat{}$}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \rar[hat] & B \dlar[hat, bend left] \\
C \uar[outgoing'] \urar[incoming']
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Or something like the [`drive off` pic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686412).